# Clear Coat too thin

Tags: paint, paint-scratches, paint-clearcoat

Painted car hood. Applied Clearcoat from a spray can. The clear coat was applied too thin, not applied wet. Can I apply more clear coat? Do I need to sand? The last application of clear was two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to help apply the material to your vehicle without having to worry about it running off of the panel your wanting to spray is to adjust your fan to where the paintgun's spray pattern is all the way open then adjust your guns fluid needle in forward to prevent the over thinned clear pulls back a bit as well as when spraying you will need to correct the spray gun distance 6 to 8 inches while speeding up your spray gun speed.